# Is there any way to hide specific span without any id and class with CSS?

Tags: html, css

e.g.
    `<span data-co="label">Select the elements you do not want to see on this page</span>`

as in above span there is no id or class given to span but i need to hide this
span

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. It depends on what about the span, or its relationship to other elements, is unique. Try read the selectors spec and see what matches with your HTML: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/

Comment: in css: span[data-co=label] { display: none; } Is one possible solution

Comment: Please read the docs before posting a question. What you ask is elementary and easy to find: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 1):

As @Olivier Krull mentioned above, you can use an attribute selector to target that span, like so:

```css
span[data-co=label] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span>This element is visible</span>
<span data-co="label">Select the elements you do not want to see on this page</span>
```

Of course, that assumes that all the spans you want to hide have that attribute.